# how to format textbox entry client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, format, mask

Q:

I wanna to mask my textbox , so if
   the user enter the number one for
   example it formatted as

**0000001** how to do this ,any number in 7 digits.

Comment: How is this related to ASP.NET or AJAX? Looks like pure JavaScript to me.

Comment: Looks like Wolfy answer is the most simple and straightforward way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going to need something like this [padding function](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-pad.html).

You could listen for a keypress then as soon as it is fired, use `getElementById()` to get your elements content, you could then run the padding function on it and put the padded value back in.

Comment: Nice, and to put this into real use simply have such textbox: `<input type="text" onchange="this.value = pad(this.value, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);" />` you can add the `onchange` in Page_Load in case this is server side textbox i.e. `<asp:Textbox>` control. Live test case is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/HwRXL/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use MaskedEditExtender in Ajax. Set its properties such as TargetControlID as your TextBox name, MaskType="Number", Mask="9999999" and AutoComplete="true". I hope it will work fine.