# Format Text upon Entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedtextbox

I tried to do my homework, but if I have an area, JS is not it -- I don't have the keywords to do any proper searching. All I know is that it might involve masking/overlaying.

I want an input element with client-side code looking for a pattern in the text a user enters, as they enter it. If they enter a phone number pattern inline with other text, I want the pattern to, for starters, get styled.

Ultimately, I'd like to figure out how to do something useful with it through AJAX.

PS. Not a duplicate of [how to format textbox entry client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667271/how-to-format-textbox-entry-client-side)

Comment: What I believe you're looking for is "content editable div".

Comment: This is confusing, can you extend what you mean by: get styled? The issue is that i'm thinking you want something like a Syntax Highlight? That would be awfully complicated for someone not familiar with JS, you make me think that because you say you want 1 input element and various styles? If you just want to add text to "logically style", like dashes to a telephone number then that's different.

Answer (score 0):

you need 3 things, an event on keypress to read the input, a regular expression to check if the pattern is matched, and method to change the style of the input.

```
$('div').delegate('input.phonenr', 'keyup', function () {
    var phonePattern = /^((00|\+)[0-9]{2})[0-9]\d{9}$/;
    var phoneNumber = this.value.replace(/\s|\-/g,'');
    if ( phonePattern.test(phoneNumber) ) $(this).css('color', 'green');
    else $(this).css('color', 'red');
    // test with 0041 798 12 21 123
});
```

or [test this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kuqz4/4/). Finally big ups to James, without who all this wouldn't have been possible. [check his great post about phone patterns and regexp from which I shamelessly copied everything ^^](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript/).

note if you want to highlight something like "sometext **phoneNumber** somemoretext" in a text (and not input box), [check this post, and overall comments, of this other james wunderpost](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/highlighting-text-with-javascript/)

note: I prefer .addClass() and .removeClass() methods to the .css() one (like in my fiddle), it's cleaner, and considered a better practice.

Comment: It depends on the pattern for a phone number. The above pattern seems to assume a country code prefix followed by a pattern that is likely specific to a small number of countries. It will not match phone numbers in my locality.

Comment: sure it's an example! with some googlefu I'm sure you can stumble upon generic pattern for countries, or even international

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a javascript rich text editor or at least something like [this](https://gist.github.com/979796) for styling.  Here is a quick and dirty example of listening for a phone number pattern in a plain textarea:

```
function interpretKeys(e) { 
  var text = e.target.value,
      matched = text.match(/(\d|-){7,15}/g);

  if (matched) alert(matched);
}

textPlace.addEventListener('keypress', interpretKeys, false);
```